# Reports that were in Adwords API no longer present in Ads API

Tags: google-ads-api

I have always referred to to Adwords API (https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports) as a guide for exporting reports from Google Ads. When moving to new Ads API (https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v6/overview) I was confused with the new feature "resources" which is the alternative for "old" reports.

Some reports in Adwords API match these resources in Ads API (Ad Group Performance) but I am unable to find matches for Account Performance Report and Criteria Performance Report. I'm not also sure that Audience Performance Report is similar to Campaign Audience View.

Can someone please explain how I can export these unmatched reports using Ads API? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an [overview page](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/migration/reports) showing which Google Adwords API report maps to which Google Ads resource.

The Account Performance Report can be recreated by querying the `customer` resource as indicated by the documentation.

The Criteria Performance Report on the other hand is not listed at all. I think you'll have to use the different `*_view` resources such as `keyword_view` in combination with fields from the `ad_group_criterion` resource in order to get metrics for different criteria types. From the [query cookbook page](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/query/cookbook#age_demographics), here's an example how to recreate the age demographics screen in the UI:

```
SELECT ad_group_criterion.age_range.type,
  campaign.name,
  ad_group.name,
  ad_group_criterion.system_serving_status,
  ad_group_criterion.bid_modifier,
  metrics.clicks,
  metrics.impressions,
  metrics.ctr,
  metrics.average_cpc,
  metrics.cost_micros,
  campaign.advertising_channel_type
FROM age_range_view
WHERE segments.date DURING LAST_7_DAYS
```