# Equivalent of CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT in Google Ads API?

Tags: google-ads-api

I want to know the equivalent of CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT(which was in Adwords) in Google Ads.

For example, the equivalent for KEYWORD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT is keyword_view.

I tried to find it a lot but couldn't get it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reports that were in Adwords API no longer present in Ads API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65779596/reports-that-were-in-adwords-api-no-longer-present-in-ads-api)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of the mappings of old to new: https://developers.google.cn/google-ads/api/docs/migration/mapping

Comment: CRITERIA PERFORMANCE REPORT not listed in the mapping.

Comment: On the page, it states:

In the Google Ads API, there are no single attribution reports. All Google Ads API criteria-level reports are multi-attribution in the sense that each report is specific to one criterion type group, and summarizes statistics according to criteria of that type. Do not add statistics together from different criteria_view resources, as that would lead to double-counting and incorrect totals.


What exactly are you looking to grab and I can write up the proper query to show you the difference.

Comment: I need to calculate spending at criteria level .

The data row should be like this,

Date,Campaign, Adgroup, Criteria Type(Keyword,Age Range,Placement etc), Criteria (keyword name , agerange name etc or display name of criteia ), Clicks, Impression, Cost